# Changed my mind on a vote for a thread, do I get that vote added for the total of the day?

Tags: discussion

I've tried searching for something similar on the Meta, I wasn't able to locate anything.

If I were to "retract" a vote from a post that I previously voted on, does that vote now get added back to my daily total?

For example, I have 4 remaining votes for the day, and I decide to retract a previous vote from an edited post that I had voted on during the same day, or from a different day.

Do I receive that vote back so that now I have 4 + 1 = 5 remaining votes?

Comment: Assuming it's possible to retract? You do know that you can only retract a vote after five minutes if the post hasn't been edited, right?

Comment: Yes I know that